# What is solution for save multiple MySQL database connections in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, transactions, connection

I need a solution for save every MySQL connections in PHP and use it in sql transactions between connections.

I know that I can't do transactions between different connections but I want to handle in PHP or a solution. (I don't know "what is the solution?")

Is that right, about :

- security?
- performance?
- transaction?
- ...

**completing question :**

I have multiple databases that connected with different users. One or more database are common between other databases that use it on the joins, for example :

```
db_common with common_user and tables: common_1, common_2, ...
db_specific_1 with user_1 and tables: s1_1, s1_2, ...
db_specific_2 with user_2 and tables: s2_1, s2_2, ...
```

May be join db_specific_1 with common or even with db_specific_2.

I want to remove joins between databases. Because, db_specific_1 is for a project and db_specific_2 is for other project. Since the database server is the same one, I granted select access to user_1 to db_specific_2, that is wrong, since db_specific_2 must be transfer to other server.

I need transaction between db_specific_1 and db_specific_2 and db_common.

Comment: You need to give us some more information about what you're trying to do. How are the connections related? Why do you need to use transactions between the connections? The question is currently too unclear and unspecific which also makes it too broad.

Comment: Thanks Magnus Erikson. I updated my question.

Comment: I think, must be use xa-transaction, please help me about this link : [about xa-transaction](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/xa-transactions/)

Answer (score 0):

I setup the access rights so that each project needs only one database connection. Usually each project has a main part of a database. For example:

```
grant all on `database`.* to `username`@localhost
```

If the same user have full access to another database2, I add

```
grant all on `database2`.* to `username`@localhost
```

But usually, only some tables or columns must be accessed, and sometime only readonly:

```
grant select on `database2`.stats to `username`@localhost
```

In PHP use `database.table` instead of `table` to select *foreign*  tables:

```
SELECT a.name, b.stat 
FROM `mytable` a 
LEFT JOIN `database2`.`stats` b ON b.id = a.id
```

Comment: I want to a solution for transaction between 2 or more database server, not code to select or grant user access to database!!! What is this?

Comment: You said: "Since the database server is the same one". And now there are different servers? Confused! Anyway, yo have always grant riights to a user. And this solutions shows a way to work with only one connection, but a join between 2 databases.

Comment: I'm sorry, I will transfer the db_specific_2 database to another server and don't have it in one server. ".. db_specific_2 must be transfer to other server"